# php artisan not working

Tags: php, laravel, artisan

Пытаюсь сделать взаимодействие проекта с Telegram ботом (без внешних библиотек).
Вроде все получается: сообщения, файлы... все отправляется - ок.

Но заметил такую странность... перестал работать artisan
Т.е. не реагирует никак, что только не пробовал.

Laravel 9.6, php 8.0.8, composer 2.3.2

Но если убрать изменения, которые я внес в следующие файлы, то artisan работает.

Изменения в \App\Exception\Handler.php

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use App\Helpers\Telegram;

    protected $telegram;

    public function __construct(Container $container, Telegram $telegram)
    {
        //
        $this->telegram = $telegram;
    }

    public function report(Throwable $e)
    {
        //
        $data = [
            'description' => $e->getMessage(),
            'file' => $e->getFile(),
            'line' => $e->getLine(),
        ];

        $this->telegram->sendMessage(env('REPORT_TELEGRAM_ID'), (string) view('err_report', $data));
    }
```

Новый файл \App\Helpers\Telegram.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;


class Telegram
{
    protected $http;
    protected $bot;
    const url = 'https://api.tlgr.org/bot';

    public function __construct(Http $http, $bot)
    {
        $this->http = $http;
        $this->bot = $bot;
    }

    public function sendMessage($chat_id, $message)
    {
        return $this->http::post(self::url . $this->bot . '/sendMessage', [
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => $message,
            'parse_mode' => 'html',
        ]);
    }

    public function editMessage($chat_id, $message, $message_id)
    {
        return $this->http::post(self::url . $this->bot . '/editMessageText', [
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => $message,
            'parse_mode' => 'html',
            'message_id' => $message_id,
        ]);
    }

    public function sendDocument($chat_id, $file, $reply_id = null)
    {
        return $this->http::attach('document', file_get_contents($file), basename($file))
            ->post(self::url . $this->bot . '/sendDocument', [
                'chat_id' => $chat_id,
                'reply_to_message_id' => $reply_id,
            ]);
    }

    public function sendButton($chat_id, $message, $button)
    {
        return $this->http::post(self::url . $this->bot . '/sendMessage', [
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => $message,
            'parse_mode' => 'html',
            'reply_markup' => $button,
        ]);
    }

    public function editButton($chat_id, $message, $button, $message_id)
    {
        return $this->http::post(self::url . $this->bot . '/editMessageText', [
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
            'text' => $message,
            'parse_mode' => 'html',
            'reply_markup' => $button,
            'message_id' => $message_id,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Возможно ли это исправить каким-то образом?

Пример вывода консоли:

```
adm@KOM x:\domains\bot.loc  
$ php artisan list                             
                                               
adm@KOM x:\domains\bot.loc
$
```

Содержимое функции в файле \Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1104, на которую указывает ошибка:

```
    /**
     * Throw an exception for an unresolvable primitive.
     *
     * @param  \ReflectionParameter  $parameter
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
     */
    protected function unresolvablePrimitive(ReflectionParameter $parameter)
    {
        $message = "Unresolvable dependency resolving [$parameter] in class {$parameter->getDeclaringClass()->getName()}";

        throw new BindingResolutionException($message); // <- this row
    }
```

Comment: Что значит не работает? Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Что отображается в консоли?

Comment: Добавил пример вывода консоли. Пытаюсь создавать новые модели, контроллеры... Да просто вывести список команд artisan и ничего. Пока не уберу или закомментирую свои изменения в в \App\Exception\Handler.php

Comment: Как будто где-то должна отобразиться ошибка, но вы ее перехватываете и отправляете куда-то в телеграм, судя по всему. Попробуйте в обработчике ошибок в метод report добавить вывод ошибки в консоль.

Comment: #23 {main}
  thrown in D:\prog\ops\domains\bot.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 1104
[01-Apr-2022 15:57:47 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [ <required> $bot ]] in class App\Helpers\Telegram in D:\prog\ops\domains\bot.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1104

Comment: Что у вас  находится в этом файле на 1104 строке?
D:\prog\ops\domains\bot.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:1104

Comment: Добавил содержимое этого файла, но это файл из коробки и он не менялся

Comment: Вы делаете Dependency Injection в Exception Handler, а где код для [сервиса](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container) Телеграма, чтобы фреймворк мог его резолвить и вставить? У вас есть класс Telegram в Helpers, но нет места где вы его создаете и передаете в обработчик исключений... Какой пакет вы используете для Телеграма?

Comment: Я обычно в такие дебри не лез) Что мне нужно сделать, запутался...

Comment: Никаких пакетов. https://api.tlgr.org/bot и вперед

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле \App\Helpers\Telegram.php
в функцию

```
    public function __construct(Http $http, $bot)
    {
        $this->http = $http;
        $this->bot = $bot;
    }
```

заменил на

```
    public function __construct(Http $http, $bot = null)
    {
        $this->http = $http;
        $this->bot = $bot;
    }
```

и ошибка ушла

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Взял отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124360/unresolvable-dependency-resolving-parameter-0-required-name

Comment: не помогло, результат тот же (((